# Physical work laptop showing up as 'virtualpc'

Tags: environment-variables, virtual-machine, zorin

I bought and installed Zorin OS Pro 16.1 (Ubuntu 20.04) and post-installation when I run the 'virt-what' command it shows up as a virtual pc. Also if I run the 'facter' command then it shows up as a Physical device however if I run the same command as 'sudo' then again it shows a virtual pc.

Another thing to note is that certain headers using the 'binwalk -z' command showed the device as a VMware4 Disk Image (after which I reinstalled the system). This is highly confusing for me, and I am not that well versed in terms of Linux understanding, extremely new to it. If anyone could please help me out and resolve this issue I would really appreciate it.

System is installed on the experimental zfs installation.

```bash
$ sudo facter

disks => {
  nvme0n1 => {
    model => "HFB1M8MO331C0MR",
    size => "238.47 GiB",
    size_bytes => 256060514304
  }
}
dmi => {
  bios => {
    release_date => "04/13/2022",
    vendor => "Microsoft Corporation",
    version => "15.10.140"
  },
  board => {
    manufacturer => "Microsoft Corporation",
    product => "Surface Pro 7",
    serial_number => "A79030044932040A"
  },
  chassis => {
    type => "Laptop"
  },
  manufacturer => "Microsoft Corporation",
  product => {
    name => "Surface Pro 7",
    serial_number => "022101104053",
    uuid => "42fa6697-7511-3ef9-3e82-55e630d2b0e1"
  }
}
facterversion => 3.11.0
filesystems => ext2,ext3,ext4,squashfs,vfat
fips_enabled => false
identity => {
  gid => 0,
  group => "root",
  privileged => true,
  uid => 0,
  user => "root"
}
is_virtual => true
kernel => Linux
kernelmajversion => 5.15
kernelrelease => 5.15.0-46-generic
kernelversion => 5.15.0
load_averages => {
  15m => 1.01,
  1m => 0.59,
  5m => 0.91
}
memory => {
  swap => {
    available => "2.00 GiB",
    available_bytes => 2144858112,
    capacity => "0.12%",
    total => "2.00 GiB",
    total_bytes => 2147479552,
    used => "2.50 MiB",
    used_bytes => 2621440
  },
  system => {
    available => "1.63 GiB",
    available_bytes => 1753829376,
    capacity => "77.81%",
    total => "7.36 GiB",
    total_bytes => 7905189888,
    used => "5.73 GiB",
    used_bytes => 6151360512
  }
}
mountpoints => {
  /boot/efi => {
    available => "497.74 MiB",
    available_bytes => 521916416,
    capacity => "2.59%",
    device => "/dev/nvme0n1p1",
    filesystem => "vfat",
    options => [
      "rw",
      "relatime",
      "fmask=0022",
      "dmask=0022",
      "codepage=437",
      "iocharset=iso8859-1",
      "shortname=mixed",
      "errors=remount-ro"
    ],
    size => "510.98 MiB",
    size_bytes => 535805952,
    used => "13.25 MiB",
    used_bytes => 13889536
  },
  /boot/grub => {
    available => "497.74 MiB",
    available_bytes => 521916416,
    capacity => "2.59%",
    device => "/dev/nvme0n1p1",
    filesystem => "vfat",
    options => [
      "rw",
      "relatime",
      "fmask=0022",
      "dmask=0022",
      "codepage=437",
      "iocharset=iso8859-1",
      "shortname=mixed",
      "errors=remount-ro"
    ],
    size => "510.98 MiB",
    size_bytes => 535805952,
    used => "13.25 MiB",
    used_bytes => 13889536
  },
  /dev/shm => {
    available => "3.68 GiB",
    available_bytes => 3952594944,
    capacity => "0%",
    device => "tmpfs",
    filesystem => "tmpfs",
    options => [
      "rw",
      "nosuid",
      "nodev",
      "inode64"
    ],
    size => "3.68 GiB",
    size_bytes => 3952594944,
    used => "0 bytes",
    used_bytes => 0
  },
  /run => {
    available => "751.70 MiB",
    available_bytes => 788217856,
    capacity => "0.29%",
    device => "tmpfs",
    filesystem => "tmpfs",
    options => [
      "rw",
      "nosuid",
      "nodev",
      "noexec",
      "relatime",
      "size=771992k",
      "mode=755",
      "inode64"
    ],
    size => "753.90 MiB",
    size_bytes => 790519808,
    used => "2.20 MiB",
    used_bytes => 2301952
  },
  /run/lock => {
    available => "5.00 MiB",
    available_bytes => 5242880,
    capacity => "0%",
    device => "tmpfs",
    filesystem => "tmpfs",
    options => [
      "rw",
      "nosuid",
      "nodev",
      "noexec",
      "relatime",
      "size=5120k",
      "inode64"
    ],
    size => "5.00 MiB",
    size_bytes => 5242880,
    used => "0 bytes",
    used_bytes => 0
  },
  /run/snapd/ns => {
    available => "751.70 MiB",
    available_bytes => 788217856,
    capacity => "0.29%",
    device => "tmpfs",
    filesystem => "tmpfs",
    options => [
      "rw",
      "nosuid",
      "nodev",
      "noexec",
      "relatime",
      "size=771992k",
      "mode=755",
      "inode64"
    ],
    size => "753.90 MiB",
    size_bytes => 790519808,
    used => "2.20 MiB",
    used_bytes => 2301952
  },
  /run/user/1000 => {
    available => "753.83 MiB",
    available_bytes => 790450176,
    capacity => "0.01%",
    device => "tmpfs",
    filesystem => "tmpfs",
    options => [
      "rw",
      "nosuid",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "size=771988k",
      "mode=700",
      "uid=1000",
      "gid=1000",
      "inode64"
    ],
    size => "753.89 MiB",
    size_bytes => 790515712,
    used => "64.00 KiB",
    used_bytes => 65536
  },
  /snap/bare/5 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop1",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "128.00 KiB",
    size_bytes => 131072,
    used => "128.00 KiB",
    used_bytes => 131072
  },
  /snap/core/13425 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop0",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "114.00 MiB",
    size_bytes => 119537664,
    used => "114.00 MiB",
    used_bytes => 119537664
  },
  /snap/core18/2538 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop2",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "55.63 MiB",
    size_bytes => 58327040,
    used => "55.63 MiB",
    used_bytes => 58327040
  },
  /snap/core22/188 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop5",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "70.50 MiB",
    size_bytes => 73924608,
    used => "70.50 MiB",
    used_bytes => 73924608
  },
  /snap/domotzpro-agent-publicstore/154 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop6",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "36.13 MiB",
    size_bytes => 37879808,
    used => "36.13 MiB",
    used_bytes => 37879808
  },
  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop3",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "164.88 MiB",
    size_bytes => 172883968,
    used => "164.88 MiB",
    used_bytes => 172883968
  },
  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop8",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "91.75 MiB",
    size_bytes => 96206848,
    used => "91.75 MiB",
    used_bytes => 96206848
  },
  /snap/htop/3417 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop7",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "9.63 MiB",
    size_bytes => 10092544,
    used => "9.63 MiB",
    used_bytes => 10092544
  },
  /snap/snapd/16292 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop9",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "47.00 MiB",
    size_bytes => 49283072,
    used => "47.00 MiB",
    used_bytes => 49283072
  },
  /snap/termius-app/129 => {
    available => "0 bytes",
    available_bytes => 0,
    capacity => "100%",
    device => "/dev/loop4",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nodev",
      "relatime",
      "errors=continue"
    ],
    size => "88.00 MiB",
    size_bytes => 92274688,
    used => "88.00 MiB",
    used_bytes => 92274688
  },
  /sys/fs/cgroup => {
    available => "3.68 GiB",
    available_bytes => 3952594944,
    capacity => "0%",
    device => "tmpfs",
    filesystem => "tmpfs",
    options => [
      "ro",
      "nosuid",
      "nodev",
      "noexec",
      "mode=755",
      "inode64"
    ],
    size => "3.68 GiB",
    size_bytes => 3952594944,
    used => "0 bytes",
    used_bytes => 0
  }
}
networking => {
  fqdn => "YKSP7",
  hostname => "YKSP7",
  interfaces => {
    lo => {
      bindings => [
        {
          address => "127.0.0.1",
          netmask => "255.0.0.0",
          network => "127.0.0.0"
        }
      ],
      bindings6 => [
        {
          address => "::1",
          netmask => "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff",
          network => "::1"
        }
      ],
      ip => "127.0.0.1",
      ip6 => "::1",
      mtu => 65536,
      netmask => "255.0.0.0",
      netmask6 => "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff",
      network => "127.0.0.0",
      network6 => "::1"
    },
    wlp0s20f3 => {
      bindings => [
        {
          address => "192.168.18.12",
          netmask => "255.255.255.0",
          network => "192.168.18.0"
        }
      ],
      bindings6 => [
        {
          address => "2400:adc1:141:6400::4",
          netmask => "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff",
          network => "2400:adc1:141:6400::4"
        },
        {
          address => "2400:adc1:141:6400:8834:a2d7:fbc2:22f3",
          netmask => "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::",
          network => "2400:adc1:141:6400::"
        },
        {
          address => "2400:adc1:141:6400:fde1:4c5b:8b46:ddc4",
          netmask => "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::",
          network => "2400:adc1:141:6400::"
        },
        {
          address => "fe80::ad48:bf89:5cc7:739a",
          netmask => "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::",
          network => "fe80::"
        }
      ],
      ip => "192.168.18.12",
      ip6 => "2400:adc1:141:6400::4",
      mac => "2c:db:07:af:04:01",
      mtu => 1500,
      netmask => "255.255.255.0",
      netmask6 => "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff",
      network => "192.168.18.0",
      network6 => "2400:adc1:141:6400::4"
    }
  },
  ip => "192.168.18.12",
  ip6 => "2400:adc1:141:6400::4",
  mac => "2c:db:07:af:04:01",
  mtu => 1500,
  netmask => "255.255.255.0",
  netmask6 => "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff",
  network => "192.168.18.0",
  network6 => "2400:adc1:141:6400::4",
  primary => "wlp0s20f3"
}
os => {
  architecture => "amd64",
  distro => {
    codename => "focal",
    description => "Zorin OS 16.1",
    id => "Zorin",
    release => {
      full => "16",
      major => "16"
    }
  },
  family => "Debian",
  hardware => "x86_64",
  name => "Debian",
  release => {
    full => "bullseye/sid",
    major => "bullseye/sid"
  },
  selinux => {
    enabled => false
  }
}
partitions => {
  /dev/loop0 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_13425.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/core/13425",
    size => "113.99 MiB",
    size_bytes => 119525376
  },
  /dev/loop1 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/bare/5",
    size => "4.00 KiB",
    size_bytes => 4096
  },
  /dev/loop2 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2538.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/core18/2538",
    size => "55.56 MiB",
    size_bytes => 58261504
  },
  /dev/loop3 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_161.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161",
    size => "164.76 MiB",
    size_bytes => 172761088
  },
  /dev/loop4 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/termius-app_129.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/termius-app/129",
    size => "87.90 MiB",
    size_bytes => 92172288
  },
  /dev/loop5 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_188.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/core22/188",
    size => "70.40 MiB",
    size_bytes => 73822208
  },
  /dev/loop6 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/domotzpro-agent-publicstore_154.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/domotzpro-agent-publicstore/154",
    size => "36.10 MiB",
    size_bytes => 37855232
  },
  /dev/loop7 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/htop_3417.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/htop/3417",
    size => "9.63 MiB",
    size_bytes => 10092544
  },
  /dev/loop8 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535",
    size => "91.69 MiB",
    size_bytes => 96141312
  },
  /dev/loop9 => {
    backing_file => "/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_16292.snap",
    filesystem => "squashfs",
    mount => "/snap/snapd/16292",
    size => "46.96 MiB",
    size_bytes => 49242112
  },
  /dev/nvme0n1p1 => {
    filesystem => "vfat",
    mount => "/boot/efi",
    partlabel => "EFI System Partition",
    partuuid => "97648142-9386-4b4a-aacd-6266135f19e6",
    size => "512.00 MiB",
    size_bytes => 536870912,
    uuid => "2AB7-F717"
  },
  /dev/nvme0n1p2 => {
    filesystem => "swap",
    partuuid => "3747d4cc-e4b1-7347-baae-31323732ab8a",
    size => "2.00 GiB",
    size_bytes => 2147483648,
    uuid => "e8c96bb7-810f-4506-bd93-eba87a863df9"
  },
  /dev/nvme0n1p3 => {
    filesystem => "zfs_member",
    label => "bpool",
    partuuid => "d6334e19-6af5-ab4b-851c-631b39fd1c47",
    size => "2.00 GiB",
    size_bytes => 2147483648,
    uuid => "714208505231915170"
  },
  /dev/nvme0n1p4 => {
    filesystem => "zfs_member",
    label => "rpool",
    partuuid => "8e960b55-9028-d641-bee7-f8a819e892c8",
    size => "233.97 GiB",
    size_bytes => 251227610624,
    uuid => "16305546322579521876"
  }
}
path => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
processors => {
  count => 8,
  isa => "x86_64",
  models => [
    "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz",
    "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz",
    "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz",
    "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz",
    "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz",
    "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz",
    "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz",
    "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G4 CPU @ 1.10GHz"
  ],
  physicalcount => 1,
  speed => "3.70 GHz"
}
ruby => {
  platform => "x86_64-linux-gnu",
  sitedir => "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.7.0",
  version => "2.7.0"
}
system_uptime => {
  days => 0,
  hours => 3,
  seconds => 11493,
  uptime => "3:11 hours"
}
timezone => PKT
virtual => virtualpc"
```

Comment: It could mean that the OS is running as a virtual machine on top of a physical VMware dom0 host, which would actually be a rather neat solution in a remote management situation which would allow an (dom0-)admin to potentially even migrate the machine to new hardware or make it part of a "cloud" of similar systems. Hmm... I don't know enough about Zorin OS so I can't really say anything that would amount to an actual answer, but anyway, potentially a very neat management solution that you as a user shouldn't really need to worry too much about at all.

Comment: Ok, so when I said work laptop I might have confused you, it is actually my own personal laptop that I use for work and should have no such remote management by default as I myself installed the operating system to replace windows (which i find to be a joke now).

Also the operating system is the equivalent of Ubuntu 20.04 running a GNOME3 desktop environment. So reading your answer actually increases my concern as unless intended that should never be the case, right?

Comment: It's unclear what your actual concerns are.  The fact that the Zorin OS is built as a virtual machine on top of VMWare does not seem like something that should be a concern.  It's, as I said, a neat solution in the case that a company wants to manage a fleet of user systems, and the fact that you don't have any use of it doesn't mean that it's a bad thing.

Comment: Oh i thought you meant from the IT admin's perspective. If that is the case then okay, I guess this can be considered to have solved my question. How would I verify this so that I can mark it as such?

Comment: I would propose to leave the question open. I will not write a proper answer that you can accept because my comments here so far are just based on guesses.  It would be better if someone who actually knows this OS either writes their own answer, or says that yes, I'm correct in my guesswork (in which case I can write my comments up as an answer).

Comment: Update:

If I remove the virt-what package then the sudo facter command once again shows up as 'physical.' So I am assuming that this has something to with the package's installation config and how that affects the appearance of the system itself and not an actual VMWare4 image. Ofcourse this would need to be further investigated, for the time being I am not going to pursue it as it seems to satisfy my curiosity thus far.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `virt-what` package enables the system to detect whether it is running as a virtual machine. If you remove it, it may not be able to detect whether it is in fact a virtual machine. If it _is_ a virtual machine or not should not make much difference to you as a user though.

Comment: Hmmm, so is that a dependency for detection or a utility? Because there are other programs such as `facter` as well that are supposed to detect it as such. This is so confusing..... it is only relevant to me if my pc is not supposed to be a virtual machine by default. Because then it is a valid security concern.